# How to send email from Gmail with sub-addressing tag?

Tags: email, gmail

I have subscribed to mailing lists using Gmail's [sub-addressing feature using plus '+' symbol](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html).

The subscribed email address is of the format `hikingfan+mailinglists@gmail.com` and I can receive emails on the same address. But when I reply to an email it is sent without the sub-address tag i.e. `hikingfan@gmail.com`.

The sent message is being held until the list moderator can review it for approval since the list considers it as a post by a non-member to a members-only list.

Since `hikingfan+mailinglists@gmail.com` is already a member of the list, is there any way to send emails with the sub-addressing tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to setup your `+` address for sending.

Go to Gmail settings by clicking the cog wheel button:
[image: Gmail settings menu]

Click the *Accounts* tab.
Click *Add another email address*. 
[image: Accounts settings]

In the popup window that appears, fill in your `+` address. Leave *Treat as an alias* checked. Click *Next step*.

That should be it, really.

From now on, you'll be able to select `hikingfan+mailinglists@gmail.com` when composing a new email - notice how the *From* box is now a dropdown list of options: 
[image: Compose window]